# parsing out the html doctype tag in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can I parse out the doctype tag to get the html version from a html file?

Trying to use doctype(or DOCTYPE or !DOCTYPE) as an argument in xpath raises an invalide expression error.

Comment: You need to show an example of your code to answer the problem. We can't try to guess what you might have missed.

Answer (score 5):

The doctype is not part of the document, but part of its DTD

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOF
<!DOCTYPE foo PUBLIC "bar" "qux">
<html>
</html>
EOF

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

puts doc.internal_subset.name
puts doc.internal_subset.external_id
puts doc.internal_subset.system_id
```

Comment: `puts doc.internal_subset.to_s #=> '<!DOCTYPE foo PUBLIC "bar" "qux">'`